# If a human were able to change its own celluar structure how would it evolve?

Tags: biology, technology, shapeshifters

Say a human gained the technology to change its own cellular structure, what ways could said human go about "evolving/modifying" itself? How far can it modify itself?

Answer (score 3):

Without a mechanism to determine the results of changes beforehand, the most likely evolution is toward permanent death. Or, for instance, if a person modified himself to produce working wings, muscles necessary to flap them, and a metabolism adequate to power the new organism, there is no guarantee that after a few hours of flight the bones won't snap or the tendons fail under the continued load, with the result being a fatal crash. How do you tell in advance what won't work?

Comment: evolution takes millions of years, in minuscule increments.  If the tiny change helps, than it will stay in the gene pool.  If not...  it dies off.